# How to reduce numerical errors when using the finite-difference method?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics

I'm trying a FDTD (Finite-Difference Time-Domain) method, however my numerical results differ from the analytical result.  For example, a simulation yielded $392\,\mathrm{nm}$ when $382\,\mathrm{nm}$ was expected.

In the cases being calculated, a wave propagates in a dielectric with a fixed permittivity and zero conductivity. I tried different setups, and found that, the smaller the grid step is, the closer the numerically calculated wavelength is to the analytical solution.

**Question:**  Is minimizing the grid spacing the only way to get more accurate results, or are there other ways to improve the simulation results?

Comment: You'll likely see grid dispersion unless you have enough grid points per wavelength.  The number depends on the FD scheme.

Comment: @JohnS In different papers I've seen different numbers like 10 grid points per wavelength or 15 or so. I've tried up to 160 points per wavelength, but the wavelength in a simulation is still 3-5 nm from the pre-calculated. The FD scheme is by far: Dielectric media with permittivity of 10 and zero conductivity.

Comment: I think you'll need to describe the calculation in more detail.  Initial conditions, size of model, 1D? Boundary conditions, etc.

Comment: The ratio of spatial grid spacing to temporal is important, too. See, for example, the numerical stability condition in the [Lax-Friedrichs method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) for first order pdes.

Comment: @JohnS The setup is: 2D grid 800x800 points, Mur's boundary conditions, dt(time step) = d(grid step)/(3*c)(c - speed of light). I just wonder, is it a common and known problem of an algorythm, or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: What equation are you modeling?

Comment: Are you far from the absorbing boundary?  Initial conditions are?  What happens if you double the grid size?

Comment: A few things to consider are... (1) how are you handling boundaries (if the media are infinite in extent to you have artificial B.C. at infinity), (2) what precision are you using for the derivatives (don't just copy out of a book), you can build multi point grid estimates for the operators (more points usually --> more precision), (3) your BC estimates better match the precision of your operators, (4) check the stability and convergence for your problem (formulae in Num Rec), (5) do you see convergence if you increase the grid?